# Find length of std::wstring

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, wstring

How can I determine the length(number of characters) in a `std::wstring`?

Using `myStr.length()` gives the byte size(I think) but its not the number of characters. Do I need to create my own function to find the number of characters or **is there a native C++ way or a native WinAPI way**?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size : Returns the number of characters in the string

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183736/stdwstring-length

Comment: "*Using `myStr.length()` gives the byte size(I think) but its not the number of characters.*" Why do you think this?

Comment: @billz is `myStr.size()` the answer or are there some caveats? If its the answer then write an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @JakeM : `myStr.length()` is the answer – your question is a bit misguided.

Comment: @All `std::wstring::size() returns the number of wide-char elements in the string. This is not the same as the number of characters (as you correctly noticed).

Unfortunately, the std::basic_string template (and thus its instantiations, such as std::string and std::wstring) is encoding-agnostic. In this sense, it is actually just a template for a string of bytes and not a string of characters.` Therefore `.size()` wont give me the number of characters.

Comment: @JakeM: Define "character"? Unicode does not define the concept of a character. It defines "codepoints", "grapheme clusters" and the like, but not "character."

Comment: @NicolBolas when I say character I just mean in the generic sense where "abc" has 3 characters

Comment: @JakeM: You're in *Unicode's* world now; there is no "generic sense". There is what is defined. And what is not. And "character" is not defined.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'd be careful with that statement.. The Unicode Standard uses the word _character_ all over the place (e.g. table 2-1: _The Unicode Standard encodes characters, not glyphs_).

Comment: @jogojapan: It also defines very clearly what it means by that. Specifically, it means "code point".

Comment: @All my whole reason for this is to convert a wstring to lowercase. So if 'character' is not defined how do people convert wstrings to lowercase(relating to the english/anlgo saxon languages)? In my case I was just going to iterate over the wstring and change each character to lowercase.

Comment: @JakeM The `tolower()` function can be used for this. Have a look at the example given on cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/tolower.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'character'. Do you talk about grapheme clusters? Code points? Code units? WHAT are you trying to do, why do you need length in 'characters'? See utf8everywhere.org for some insights..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::wstring::length()` will give you the number of characters, where *character* is defined as the atomic unit of the `wstring` object, i.e. a `wchar`. This is what the Standard means when it refers to `characters` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476899/777186) for some more details on the use of the word in the Standard).

However, when it comes to Unicode characters, whether one `wchar` corresponds to one Unicode character depends on the encoding used inside the `wstring`. If UTF-16 is used, which is often (but not necessarily) the case, one `wchar` will correspond to one Unicode character only for the base multilingual plane (i.e. all character sets derived from ISO-8859 as well as most of the commonly used CJK characters, but not some of the more exotic (e.g. classical Chinese) characters)<sup>(*)</sup>. If you want to get the character count right for *all* Unicode characters in that case, you need to use a Unicode-aware library (e.g. ICU), or code it yourself.

<sup>(*)</sup>There are additional problems if *combining characters* are used, as @一二三 points out correctly. Counting those correctly is also best done using appropriate libraries.

Comment: "*If UTF-16 is used, which is commonly*" If by "commonly", you mean "on Windows".

Comment: @NicolBolas I'll change it to _often_ :)

Comment: Even within the BMP for UTF-16, combining forms and presentation forms may make one "character" appear as two `wchar`s (and vice versa).

Comment: @一二三 Very true! I've added a footnote for this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know the length in `wchar_t` entities, use `myStr.length()`. If you want to know the size in Unicode codepoints you'll have to find a library that knows how to count those. You could also write one yourself - the rules for determining whether a codepoint encoded as UTF-16 uses one or two entities are not too hard, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-16. To know if your `wchar_t` is 16 bits (vs. 32 bits) use `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`.